# Finding spatial views with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, spatial-view

Is it possible to distinguish (with ArcPy) a featureclass in an RDBMS (SQL Server, in this case) that is a table vs a registered [spatial view](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2013/10/04/do-this-not-that-alternatives-to-using-sde-command-line-tools/) that was created with the command line tools?

Spatial view is stored in an ArcSDE 10.0 geodatabase, and arcpy version <= 10.3.1.

Comment: Shouldn't use `sdetable` to create views (except for SDEBINARY geometry, which shouldn't be used, either). Please specify ArcGIS version.

Comment: ArcPy doesn't distinguish between feature classes based on tables and those based on views, and ArcObjects doesn't seem to, either.  So then it becomes an exercise in using an `arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute` cursor for an RDBMS-specific view test.  10.0 geodatabases are not supported by 10.4.x or 10.5, so leaving the database back at 10.0 is likely to cause issues soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@Vince pointed out](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/222738/how-to-find-spatial-views-with-arcpy#comment343418_222738) the `arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute` command.

Here is a function I put together to return True/False for finding a Spatial View, based on the code sample from http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/arcsdesqlexecute.htm

```
def isSpatialView(egdb, fc):
    desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    fcName = desc.name
    db, schema, tableName = fcName.split(".")

    #Connect to the GDB
    egdb_conn = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(egdb)

    #Execute SQL against the table
    sql = r"IF EXISTS(select * FROM sys.views where name = '{0}') SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0".format(tableName)

    egdb_return = egdb_conn.execute(sql)
    if egdb_return == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False


#Connect to your DB
egdb = r'Database Connections\Connection to [your_database].sde'

#Set the ArcGIS workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = egdb 

#Get all feature classes in the workspace
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

#report if featureclass is a Spatial View
for fc in fcList:
    arcpy.AddMessage( isSpatialView(egdb, fc) )
```